# Simple recursive binary converter bug

Tags: python, recursion, binary

```
def dec2binr(n):
    if n == 1:
        return '1' 
    else: return (str(n%2)+dec2binr(n//2))[::-1]
```

Without the [::-1] it returns the reversed correct binary number. The [::-1] does not work in this case - for n=40 Ii get:

```
011000
```

when i would expect

```
101000
```

Without [::-1] I get

```
000101
```

Which is reversed, but correct.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need a base case for `0`, too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's true, but when `0` is passed in, we return `str(n%2)` concatenated with the result of a recursive function call (again, with an argument of `0`)

Comment: Good point, he needs a base case for 0..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reverse how you append the strings.

```
return dec2binr(n//2) + str(n%2)
```

The issue is, `n%2` will read the least significant bit, but you were appending it to the left of the string, which is the most significant place.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you reverse *on each return*, jumbling up the bits. Either unreverse on return from the recursion, or only reverse when returning the final result (hint: helper function).